# como puedo leer correo gmail con nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, scraping, gmail

**hola a todos**

Tengo un desafio en mi trabajo el cual me pidieron hacer un scraping a un gmail al que llegan los formularios de contactos desde la web de la empresa. Les presente una propuesta en python la cual era funcional pero no en el lenguaje que les convenciera asi que me pidieron hacerlo con node js y no he encontrado informacion de como LEER un gmail con node solo de como enviar de eso he encontrado bastante, si alguien me pudiese ayudar u orientar de como realizarlo

Comment: podrías utilizar `Puppeteer` se utiliza para hacer `scarping` con `node`.

Comment: Considera que por no ajustarse a [ask] es seguro te cierren la publicación

Comment: En mi opinión, creo que si ya tienes el trabajo echo, pues no lo vuelvas a hacer. Si quieres hacer una integración con nodejs y express (por ejemplo), puedes hacer llamadas desde nodejs a phyton. Y así resuelves el dilema de integración. Si el lenguage no les convencio aunque el trabajo es bueno, pues...